# Sitecore Advanced Database Crawler numeric dynamic fields

Tags: c#, sitecore

With ADC / scSearchContrib, is it possible for a dynamic field to be treated as numeric in lucene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the `NumberFieldCrawler` class in the `scSearchContrib` solution has led to me the answer I think.

it contains the following code which seems to be what Lucene needs.

```
 long value;

 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_field.Value) && long.TryParse(_field.Value, out value))
 {
     return NumberTools.LongToString(value);
 }
```

Comment: Be careful though, I've seen strange issues using that function where scSearchContrib is formatting it differently than the native Lucene.NET in Sitecore. If you're having trouble getting any results, compare the result of NumberTools.LongToString(value) with whatever is getting stored in your index.

Answer (score 1):

Download the source of the Crawler [here](http://sitecorian.github.io/SitecoreSearchContrib/)

There is an example of a custom FieldCrawler for a dynamic field in the class `AllTemplatesField`

Also notice that this custom FieldCrawler is added in the web.config in the section `/crawlers/dynamicFields/`

This should get you started, I guess.

Comment: My question was badly worded, so I have changed it, but your answer was helpful. thanks.